# Finding a frame with the most 'weight' in a video classification problem

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I am starting a project with the task to recognize micro expressions in a human face. However, the first task that I formulated is to get the key frames in a 10 second video that has the most relation with the predicted expression. For eg, raising your eyebrows may represent surprise, but the raising activity may occur in only in say 10 frames and that 10 frames represents the micro expression for surprise. Any guides or research papers you can direct me to would be much helpful. I was planning to use some form of 3D-CNN, but I also welcome more efficient ways to do this as 3D CNN's are quite computationally expensive.

Answer (score 0):

This would come under "Action Recognition". I think it should be able to handle your requirement. You need not find the key frames.

Torch-vision has some pre-trained models which you can directly use in pytorch or you can fine-tune them with very less data. Look for "Video classification" models in this [Link](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/models.html).

I would suggest to go for R(2+1)D ([paper Link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.11248))

It is able to identify sports actions, gesture actions and sign-language.

Comment: Thank you for the links. Identifying key frames is part of what I'd like to do. For instance, I don't exactly know the features that represents an expression. So, I need to classify a video in a way such a n% of frames are neutral and 1-n% of frames represent the micro expression. I believe I would be able to do that with the paper you have referred, but I'd like to confirm.

Comment: @Balaganesh, yeah the architecture is designed in a way that it will automatically figure out the key frames itself. Just make sure your annotation is correct.